# index out of range (1 > number of parameters, which is 0)

Tags: mysql, database, jsp

When I execute this :

```
 PreparedStatement pst  = conn.prepareStatement("Update registration set First_Name='"+fstNam+"',"
            +"Last_Name='"+lstName+"',Email="+email+",Country='"+county+"',"
            +"City='"+cty+"', Gender='"+gndr+"',U_N='"+User+"',Birth_Date='"+ddd+"', Language='"+lngug+"',"
            +"Religion='"+rlign+"'  where ID='"+ID+"' ");


pst.setString(1, fstNam);
pst.setString(2, lstName);
pst.setString(3, User);
pst.setString(4, email);
pst.setString(5, county);
pst.setString(6, cty);
pst.setString(7, gndr);
pst.setString(8, ddd );
pst.setString(9, lngug);
pst.setString(10, rlign);



int l = pst.executeUpdate()
```

I get the following error:

```
 index out of range (1 > number of parameters, which is 0)
```

Is my query correct or there is any other problem?

Comment: Your SQL does not have any placeholders for the parameters. You need a `?` in the SQL wherever you want a value to be passed using `setString()`. See here for details: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html

Comment: problem solved thank's for the help........:)